# Show that $|x| = |y|$ are the only solution to the equality $\dfrac{x(4^x-2^y)}{(4^x+2^y)}=\dfrac{y(4^y-2^x)}{(4^y+2^x)}$

Tags: inequality

Show that $|x| = |y|$ are the only solutions to the equality $\dfrac{x(4^x-2^y)}{(4^x+2^y)}=\dfrac{y(4^y-2^x)}{(4^y+2^x)}$

Need help solving the question. Do not know where to start.

Comment: Restricted to integers?  OK... reals.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The question didn't specify. I would assume over real numbers. But I'm curious about your thoughts if it was restricted to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let us begin with some simplification. We have,
\begin{align*}
\frac{x(4^x - 2^y)}{(4^x + 2^y)} & = \frac{y(4^y - 2^x)}{(4^y + 2^x)} \\
\implies x(4^x - 2^y)(4^y + 2^x) & = y(4^y - 2^x)(4^x + 2^y).
\end{align*}
With a little bit of rearrangement, we obtain that the above equation is equivalent to
$$(4^{x+y} - 2^{x+y})(x-y) + (8^x - 8^y)(x + y) = 0.$$

We define the sign function as follows:
\begin{align*}
\text{sgn}(t) = \begin{cases} +1 & \text{ if } t > 0 \\ -1, & \text{ if } t < 0, \\ 0 & \text{ if } t = 0 \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Note that $\text{sgn}(x-y) = \text{sgn}(8^x - 8^y)$ and $\text{sgn}(x+y) = \text{sgn}(4^{x+y} - 2^{x+y})$.  Consequently, $\text{sgn}((4^{x+y} - 2^{x+y})(x-y)) = \text{sgn}((8^x - 8^y)(x + y))$. Hence, the only way our equation can be true is when $\text{sgn}((4^{x+y} - 2^{x+y})(x-y)) = \text{sgn}((8^x - 8^y)(x + y)) = 0$, or equivalently, $(4^{x+y} - 2^{x+y})(x-y) = (8^x - 8^y)(x + y) = 0$. The only solution to this set of equations is $|x| = |y|$, as required.

Comment: Nice use of sgn!